# cannot connect rds instance with java web app

Tags: java, jsp, rds

I am trying to connect my java app with aws rds. I have tomcat server in my local PC and i have also attached mysql JAR file with my project.
Here is my sample code

```
<%@  page import="java.sql.*" %>

 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <%
   try
  {

out.println("enter1");
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
out.println("enter");
Connection co=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://database- 
1.cpeyabyxnhkp.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/bank","kart","123678");  

 Statement st = co.createStatement();
 out.println("enter2");
}
catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}





 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When i run the server only enter1 is printing not enter but i am not getting what is the problem in **Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");**

Comment: any exception is throws..

Comment: No exception is thrown when i write   e.printStackTrace();